# Как очистить все листы класса рефлексией при уничтожении?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Есть класс, в нем ОЧЕНЬ много листов `List<SomeClass>`.
Класс не синглтон и не статичный, есть несколько инстансов этого класса.

Нужно при деструкте (`~MyContainerClass(){}`) как-то получить ссылки на все листы уничтожаемого инстанса, очистить их и обнуллить.

С рефлексией пока дружу очень слабо, нужна помощь в коде или отсылка на методы, которыми можно получить поля инстансного объекта.

Спасибо.

Comment: Класс может создаваться/удаляться произвольно, листы хранят делегаты (событий). Думаю, что GC не сможет собрать эти листы и слушатели так и будут подписаны на них, и начнутся утечки.

Или я не прав, и листы очищаются при исчезновении ссылки на них?

Comment: И, да, руками чистить все листы не вариант - их очень много, и есть риск что при добавлении нового события я просто забуду описать его ещё и в деструкторе - со всеми вытекающими.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь, автор опозорился...
Ссылки на листы есть только в этом классе, значит GC тоже соберет листы, и на элементы листов тоже не останется ссылок.

Модераторы, закройте, пожалуйста, вопрос.